# How to realise multiple text editing from one button?

Tags: android, android-edittext, counter

Here is the goal: 1 textview, 1 button. after pressing button text in  textview is editing to new string. I tryed to realise it like this, but it 
doesn`t work. Please help. There is 1 activity, 1 button, 1 tv and multiple pressings to edit text.

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;
Button btn;
int i;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second2);

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
i = 1;
tv.setText(R.string.s1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
for (i=1;i<28;i++);{

switch (i){

case 1:tv.setText(R.string.s1);
break;

case 2:tv.setText(R.string.s2);
break;

case 3:tv.setText(R.string.s3);
break;

case 4:tv.setText(R.string.s4);
break;

case 5:tv.setText(R.string.s5);
break;

case 6:tv.setText(R.string.s6);
break;

case 7:tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tigs);
tv.setHeight(430);
tv.setWidth(350);
tv.setText(R.string.s6_1);
break;

default:break;
```

What i`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At the end you will only see the value of R.string.s6 in your edit text and the background will be set as R.drawable.tigs. The for loop executes in a fraction of second and set value one by one. But due to its fast execution you will only see the last value. But if you want to see all the text one by one you can use a java thread and call its sleep method by passing the time in milliseconds.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but i need to edit text once by one press button.

Comment: @ded-logoped I have updated my answer. Please let me know this is what you want to do ?